# how to select data from an array dynamically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array like

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'John', status: 'completed' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Sam', status: 'pending' }, 
  { id: 3, name: 'Joe', status: 'in process' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Mak', status: 'completed' }
]
```

What is the best way to select data dynamically from array? e.g if i pass say id and status

I tried this

```
array.select {|a| a[:id] == 1 && a[:status] == 'completed' }
```

But user can just pass just id or combination of id and name.

Comment: You have tagged this question with `ruby-on-rails-4`. Do you really have a plain array containing hashes or are you actually dealing with records stored in a database? If so, you should use Rails' [built-in finders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html), e.g. `YourModel.find_by(id: 1, status: 'completed')`

Answer (score 1):

One way to select elements from your array by `id` or by both `id` and `status` would be to move your `select` logic into a method and expand it account for the optional status parameter, like so:

```
array = [ { id: 1, name: 'John', status: 'completed' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Sam', status: 'pending' }, 
          { id: 3, name: 'Joe', status: 'in process' },
          { id: 4, name: 'Mak', status: 'completed' }
        ]

def select_by(arr, id:, status: nil)
  arr.select do |hash|
    next unless hash[:id] == id
    next unless status && hash[:status] == status
    true
  end
end

select_by(array, id: 1)
# => [{:id=>1, :name=>"John", :status=>"completed"}]
select_by(array, id: 2, status: 'pending')
# => [{:id=>2, :name=>"Sam", :status=>"pending"}]
select_by(array, id: 3, status: 'not a real status')
# => []
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to make some changes but i couldn't get the results. Please check the code here https://repl.it/@SK121212/EasygoingMixedHoiho

Comment: Maybe `def select_by(*key_value_pairs)`?

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
id = 1
status = 'completed'

array.select { |item| item[:id] == id && (status ? item[:status] == status : true) }
# => [{:id=>1, :name=>"John", :status=>"completed"}]

status = 'foo'
array.select { |item| item[:id] == id && (status ? item[:status] == status : true) }
# => []

status = nil
array.select { |item| item[:id] == id && (status ? item[:status] == status : true) }
# => [{:id=>1, :name=>"John", :status=>"completed"}]
```

it will only compare status if it's not `nil`.